# How to use choco install winrar or other command to enable the cascaded context menu?

Tags: windows-10, context-menu, winrar, chocolatey

### Context

I use chocolatey as a package manager or software manager on different (remote) systems. WinRAR is also in my top 10 of software to be installed on new systems. I used ninite.com before, but Choco offers more applications and is fast, so now my goto-software is in order of priority is:

1. Chocolately
2. Windows Store (I know, but it auto-updates software)
3. Download-it-yourself + virustotal.com

### Case

Choco uses the default installation of most software packages, winRAR has always bugged me with starting a crusade [taking over the context menu](https://www.intowindows.com/clean-up-right-click-menu-by-enabling-cascading-menu-for-winrar/). VLC also has this [similar habit of extending the context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894233/how-to-remove-the-right-click-menu-in-vlc-media-player) with 1 or 2 items that one never uses.

This site https://chocolatey.org/packages/winrar mentions the parameters to be set:

`choco install packageID [other options] --params="'/ITEM:value /ITEM2:value2 /FLAG_BOOLEAN'"`

### Question

How do I use choco parameters to tell it to enable cascaded menu in winRAR?

I am assuming the package does not offer this parameter, is that correct?

So if that not possible. What command could I use in a Powershell script to run after `choco install winrar` to have the same result?

Please be aware that the install script might run under System and the customisation might need to run separate in a user-context. That is okay if that is a requirement.